# Работа с библиотекой itextsharp 5.3.4.0. Трудности с локальными ссылками в PDF-документе

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Всем добрый день!
Есть задача:
Получить ссылки, содержащиеся в PDF. Потом получать номер страницы, на которую направляет ссылка. И сдвинуть эту ссылку на 10 страниц вперед (т.е., напр., была ссылка на 5-ю страницу, а надо, чтобы она была на 15-ю).

Удалось получить массив `Destination`, но как получить оттуда номер страницы и изменить его, не знаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

### Код следующий:

```
Reader:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(OutFileName);
PageCount:=Reader.NumberOfPages;
For i:=1 To PageCount Do
    PageDictionary:=Reader.GetPageN(i);
    If PageDictionary.Contains(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS) Then
        annots := PageDictionary.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.Annots );
        For Each A In Annots.ArrayList Do
            AnnotationDictionary:= iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A) As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;

            ////Проверяем, что AnnotationDictionary содержит LINK и ACTION////
            If (AnnotationDictionary.@Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTY PE).Equals(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.LINK))
            And (AnnotationDictionary.@Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.A)<>N ull) Then
                ////берем Action////
                AnnotationAction:= AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.A );
                ////берем Destination////
                Dest_Array:=AnnotationAction.GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf. PdfName.D); 
            End If;
        End For;
    End If;
End For;
```

Comment: @Irina_1001, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Я собираюсь предположить, что вы делаете это, потому что вы объединяете два документа, и хотите, чтобы ссылки во втором документе указывали на правильную позицию.

Если вы используете последнюю версию iText7, вам не нужно это делать. PdfMerger автоматически изменит адресаты ссылок для вас.

Проверьте образцы кода в http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-merging-pdf-documents